# ¿Cual es la etimología de "sarpullido"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

Mi primera pregunta aquí, *alors soyez doux*.

[Wiktionary la define](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sarpullido), pero sin etimología. Y https://spanishetymology.com no tiene nada.

Comment: Aquí hay un texto bastante extenso al respecto: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?sarpullido

Comment: The dictionary of the royal academy also gives an etymology https://dle.rae.es/sarpullido?m=form

Answer (score 1):

---

¿Qué tal? - ¿Cuál es la etimología de "sarpullido"?

El sarpullido --también conocido como *salpullido*, *dermatitis*, o *erupción* de la piel-- es un área de la piel inflamada o irritada y que generalmente causa picazón. También puede ser seco, escamoso o doloroso. La mayoría de los sarpullidos ocurren cuando la piel entra en contacto con una sustancia que la irrita.

Contradiciendo todo lo que he leído, ya que no me aclara mucho, como Etimólogo, y haciendo un pequeño estudio de la voz, "sarpullido", te puedo decir que en principio la palabra, "sarpullido", procede realmente de "salpullido" y no a la inversa, aunque ambas formas son correctas, produciéndose una especie de rotacismo: la "l" se convierte en "r".

El verbo "salpullir", independientemente de cualquier otros síntomas de erupción en la piel y que dependerán de su extensión y gravedad, significa causar una erupción leve de la piel con manchas, granos y ronchas (aparición de muchos granitos o ronchas).

El origen de la palabra y su procedencia estaría principalmente relacionado con las picaduras de algunos insectos, en este caso las picaduras que dan origen a salpullido serían las ocasionadas por las pulgas.

Así tenemos que "*salpullido*" procede de dos palabras latinas sal + pulex.

La palabra "Sal", procede de los antiguos "Salios", sacerdotes de Marte y unos de los más poderosos de Roma, cuya característica principal era la de danzar en sus procesiones dando grandes saltos. Estos sacerdotes según los casos iban vestidos de rojo o cubiertos con capas rojas, color que les simbolizaba y que se tomará para indicar la extensión o los saltos de esos granos o ronchas.

Por otra parte, está la palabra pulex/pulicis, en latín vulgar "pulica" y que es el nombre que recibían las pulgas.

Así, el "salpullido" ó "salpullir", podríamos traducirlo como el "**Baile de  pulgas rojas**", por ser el salpullido de color rojo como los Saliaris", al estar extendido por una superficie más o menos extensa, según los casos, a modo de danza y tener el mismo aspecto que las picaduras de las pulgas en los humanos.

Viene a decir, tienes lo mismo que cuando te pican las pulgas, por cierto, algo más común de lo que creemos en la antigüedad. Esta voz es la que va a servir para indicar la aparición de cierta cantidad de granitos o ronchas, y que dará origen a cualquier otro tipo de salpullido, hinchazón, picaduras...que muestre la misma apariencia.

[image]

*Salpullido*

[image]

*Picadura por pulgas*

P-D. Invito a que haga una comparación entre distintos salpullidos y las picaduras de las pulgas en humanos para que confronte su parecido.

Estepero haber ayudado. Saludos.

Diego M.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tanto la forma *sarpullido* como *salpullido* eran usadas ya en el siglo XVII. Sin embargo, tanto Covarrubias (1611) como el *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1739) consideran *sarpullido* como la forma principal. Ambos diccionarios consideran la palabra como relacionada con *serpendo*, dado que los sarpullidos recorren todo el cuerpo.

Hoy día, Corominas afirma lo siguiente en su diccionario etimológico:

> Derivado de *sarpullo* [...], voz de procedencia leonesa o gallegoportuguesa [...], que probablemente procede del lat. vg. *SERPUCǓLUS, lat. tardío SERPUSCULUS 'especie de herpe o empeine', derivado de SERPĔRE 'cundir'.

Corominas da por cierta, pues, la etimología de Covarrubias, y rechaza la etimología propuesta por el italiano Pisani, por la cual vendría de SALE PULLUS, dado que una voz tan corriente como SAL no debería haber sonorizado en P- inicial la siguiente palabra, sino que se habría suavizado en B, como el portugués *sarabulho*.

El texto más antiguo que he encontrado que usa la palabra es el siguiente:

> Quando enel cuerpo salen torondos
> vermeios o sarpollido
> con mucha comezon
>
> Alfonso Chirino, "Menor daño de la medicina. Escorial, b.IV.34.", a 1429.